# How can I correct this code so that it gives the expected result

Tags: c, linux

I have created a program to mimmic the 'cat' command in linux.
I want to make a program to cater the '-n' option of 'cat' that displays line number along with the file contents.
Here is what I have done so far.

```
int numline = 1;
int i = 2;

printf("\t%d  ", numline);

for(i; i < argc ; i++)
{
    fptr = fopen(argv[i], "r");
    if(fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can not open file");
        return -1;  
    }

    c = fgetc(fptr);
    while(c != EOF)
    {
        if(c == '\n')
        {
            numline++;
            printf("\n\t%d  ", numline);    
        }
        else
            printf("%c", c);
        c = fgetc(fptr);
    }
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

Here is a sample output.

```
1  hi how are you
2  
3  
4  i am fine
5  
6  thank you
7  
8  bye
9  cya
10  garbage text
11  
12  
13  bye
14
```

The problem is with line 14. The file ends at line 13 but the program prints line 14 anyway. How do I correct this?
Thank you.

Comment: You should probably reference the sources for [`cat.c`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/cat.c) from CoreUtils.

Comment: Increase numline but do not print the line number yet.

Comment: @purpletentacle when do I print the line number?

Comment: One way is to keep a count of the characters on the line.  When you print a newline, set the count to zero.  Before printing a regular (non-newline) character, if the count is zero, print the line number information (then print the character and increase the count).

Comment: You don't show how `c` is defined.  Make sure it is `int c;` and not `char c;`.  The is no point in writing the first `i` in `for (i; i < argc; i++)`; either defer the intialization so you write `for (i = 2; i < argc; i++)` or omit the leading expression in the `for` loop control.  I'd go with the former.  If you have C99 or C11 or C18 available, use `for (int i = 2; i < argv; i++)` instead (and don't define `i` outside the loop).  It's a good idea to report errors on `stderr` (not `stdout`).  It's a good idea to include the file name in the error message when you fail to open a file.

Comment: Read [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Be aware that *stdio* is buffered, and `stdout` is often line-buffered. So prefer `\n`at end of `printf` format strings (or use `fflush`)

Answer (score 2):

On reading, `'\n'` indicates the end-of-line in text files, not the start of a new one even if C calls it a *new line*.

Rather than test `if (c == '\n')` to determine a new line,  check if the *previous c* was a `'\n'`.

Be sure to use `int c`.

```
// Commented out, not needed
// printf("\t%d  ", numline);

int c;
int previous_c = '\n';
while((c = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF) {
  if (previous_c == '\n') {
    numline++;
    printf("%d  ", ++numline);    
  }
  printf("%c", c);
  previous_c = c;
}
```

---

As the last character of input may differ from `'\n'`, code could detect that after the loop and add one.

```
if (previous_c != '\n') {
  printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the last line terminates with `\n`.
You need to restructure your program so that `numline` is only incremented if there is a char following `\n`

Answer (score 0):

Move `printf("\n\t%d  ", numline);`  from the `if` loop and place it after checking if a character is available on the next line.

```
if((c = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF)
    printf("\n\t%d  ", numline);
```

Comment: The problem is that EOF tests as 'true', so the line number will be printed as before.

Comment: Yeah, EOF is negative (usually -1). Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround for the while loop that fixes the issue. This works only if there is a maximum of one newline at the end of each line. If multiple newlines are expected a more general approach is necessary.

```
while( c != EOF )
    {
    if( c == '\n' )
        {
        c = fgetc( fptr );
        numline++;
        if( c != EOF )
            {
            printf( "\n\t%d  ", numline );
            }
        }
    else
        {
        printf( "%c", c );
        c = fgetc( fptr );
        }
    }
```

Comment: This still checks `c` (a `char`) against `EOF` (an `int` constant) though!

Comment: I reused the original code to create a working example, but yeah that can be improved too